# Get Display Name from a c# class member doesn't work in Blazor if using multi-culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I need to retrieve the display name of a class member using the function show at the bottom, but it doesn't work if I use a resource file for multi-culture.

[image]

```
    EditForm
    SfTextBox @bind-Value="@rowSelected.Name" Placeholder="@GetDisplayName("Name")"
    
     public class Account
     {
       [Display(Name = "Name on Account")]
       public string Name { get; set; }
     }
```

[image]

```
    EditForm
    SfTextBox @bind-Value="@rowSelected.Name" Placeholder="@GetDisplayName("Name")"
    
     public class Account
     {
       [Display(ResourceType = typeof(@Resources), Name = "AccountName")]
       public string Name { get; set; }
     }
```

[image]

NOTE: The resource file works ok on other components that don't need to call this function, such as grid column headers

GridColumn Field=@nameof(Account.Name) AutoFit="true"
[image]

```
public string GetDisplayName(string col)
{
    var name = "";
    MemberInfo property = typeof(Account).GetProperty(col);
    var dd = property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute)) as DisplayAttribute;
    if (dd != null)
    {
       name = dd.Name;
    }
    return name;
}
```

Comment: Your method returns the value of the `Name` property, it's not loading anything from a resource file.

Comment: In your `GetDisplayName` function, after getting the name from the attribute, I think you should then call `Resources.GetString(name)`.

Comment: Timothy Macharia OK. If you can change it to an answer I will accept it to close this thread.